# Wildcard module for importing text not type checking

Tags: typescript

Here's the wildcard module definition:

```
declare module 'text!*' {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
```

And the import:

```
import * as html from 'text!./myHtml.html';
```

And the compiler error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof 'text!*'' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'string | ((this: HTMLElement, index: number,
>   oldhtml: string) => string)'.

I'm really expect `html` to have type `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm really expect html to have type string.

Then, change the export to be a string. I show the invalid and correct code below

## Invalid

```
declare module 'text!*' {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
```

## Correct

```
declare module 'text!*' {
    const content: string;
    export = content;
}
```